How does Keychain Access decide what goes in My Certificates?
I have a .pem file I need to use for accessing a website. I have added it to Keychain Access, however it only shows up in All Items (under System) and not under My Certificates. When I visit the website, it does not show up in the various options that I can select (in Chrome) for certificates to use.
I surmise that this is because it's only in All Items and not My Certificates, although I could be wrong. How does Keychain Access decide whether to add a certificate to My Certificates when I import it?

The .pem file needs to be added to the login or System keychain. https://support.apple.com/guide/keychain-access/add-certificates-to-a-keychain-kyca2431/mac
